# 404 on _wdt: Symfony WebProfiler doesn't generate any profile data

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, profiler

Symfony2 fires lots of 404 in developer-mode when i want to enable the web profiler toolbar:

```
GET http://www.domain.dev/_wdt/de040c 404 (Not Found)
```

So i debugged the ProfilerController and discovered that it fires 404 when there is no profile-data found in filesystem.

But with every request to the page there will be new directories created under the directory "app/cache/dev/profiler", but still no files.

The file tree under app/cache/dev looks like:

[image]

As you can see, the directory "profiler" contains some directories (and it will be growing with every request to the site), but never any files. There are full write permissions for the nginx and php process, i also configured the cache-directory as an example to use shared memory under /dev/shm to prevent side effects with my host-system (i'm using vagrant for development)

So my question is: why are there no profiler data created, and "who" will be responsible for that?

#### UPDATE:

i found out, that in FileProfileStorage.php all profile data will be collected and serialized:

```
// Store profile
$data = array(
    'token' => $profile->getToken(),
    'parent' => $profile->getParentToken(),
    'children' => array_map(function ($p) { return $p->getToken(); }, $profile->getChildren()),
    'data' => $profile->getCollectors(),
    'ip' => $profile->getIp(),
    'method' => $profile->getMethod(),
    'url' => $profile->getUrl(),
    'time' => $profile->getTime(),
);

if (false === file_put_contents($file, serialize($data))) {
    return false;
}
```

Here an exception will be thrown "Serialization of Closure is not allowed". I still haven't found out which DataCollector will be responsible for using a Closure instead of "real" data.

#### UPDATE 2:

i figured out that the ProfilerExtension of TwigCacheBundle will throw exception here ("Serialization of Closures is not supported")

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by myself. ProfilerExtension of TwigCacheBundle raised the exception while being on serialization its data for the Web Profiler.

I've made a [pull request for that](https://github.com/EmanueleMinotto/TwigCacheBundle/pull/7).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. But in my case the serialization required to much memory.
After increasing PHP's memory limit to `256M`, the error disappeared.

Maybe this will help someone with the same problem.